# Python syntactic sugar: function arg aliases

Tags: python, syntax, programming-languages, pep

Is there any syntax for aliasing function args? If not, are there any PEP proposals? I'm not a programming languages theorist, so my opinion is probably uninformed, but I think implementing some sort of function arg aliasing could be useful.

I'm doing some changes to [libcloud](https://libcloud.apache.org/) and my idea would help me avoid breaking others while making changes to the APIs.

For example, say I'm refactoring and would like to rename a function arg 'foo' to 'bar':

Original:

```
def fn(foo):
    <code (using 'foo')>
```

I could:

```
def fn(foo, bar=None):
    if foo and bar:
        raise Exception('Please use foo and bar mutually exclusively.')
    bar = foo or bar
    <code (using 'bar')>

# But this is undesirable because it changes the method signature to allow
# a new parameter slot.
fn('hello world', 'goodbye world')
```

My unrefined syntactic sugar idea:

```
def fn(bar|foo|baz):
    # Callers can use foo, bar, or baz, but only the leftmost arg name
    # is used in the method code block. In this case, it would be bar.
    # The python runtime would enforce mutual exclusion between foo,
    # bar, and baz.
    <code (using 'bar')>

# Valid uses:
fn(foo='hello world')
fn(bar='hello world')
fn(baz='hello world')
fn('hello world')

# Invalid uses (would raise some exception):
fn(foo='hello world', bar='goodbye world')
fn('hello world', baz='goodbye world')
```

Comment: Doesn't exist. But you could do something like that with keyword arguments (`**kwargs`) and decorators ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No perhapses, you can do that with decorators (as shown above), or for first hand with kwargs:

```
def fn (**kw):
    arg = kw.get("foo") or kw.get("bar") or kw.get("baz")
    if arg==None: raise TypeError, "foo nor bar nor baz given az argument"
    print arg

Here the order of precedence is: "if foo exists, arg is foo. if it doesn't but bar exists, arg is bar, if neither foo nor bar exists, the arg is baz. If baz doesn't, i.e. all 3 are missing, arg is None.

Of course, you may check whether either one exists and force the mutual exclusion, but I don't see why would you need such a thing.

You are clever and you will never pass them in together. Even if you do, some will be ignored.
```

You can also do it with callable objects, even introduce your syntax and behavior into the interpreter at runtime if you want.

But in my opinion, introducing this as a valid Python syntax is not Pythonic and would never happen, even if there is a PEP.

As you can see, you can do what you want without dirtying Python syntax.

I don't mean that your example is not syntactically clear, just unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no such syntactic sugar.

You could use `**kwargs` to capture extra keyword arguments and look for deprecated names in that (and raise an exception if there are not there). You could even automate that with a decorator perhaps.

```
from functools import wraps

def renamed_argument(old_name, new_name):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if old_name in kwargs:
                if new_name in kwargs:
                    raise ValueError(
                        "Can't use both the old name {} and new name {}. "
                        "The new name is preferred.".format(old_name, new_name))
                kwargs[new_name] = kwargs.pop(old_name)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@renamed_argument('bar', 'foo')
def fn(foo=None):
    <method code>
```

Demo:

```
>>> @renamed_argument('bar', 'foo')
... def fn(foo=None):
...     return foo
...
>>> fn()  # default None returned
>>> fn(foo='spam')
'spam'
>>> fn(bar='spam')
'spam'
>>> fn(foo='eggs', bar='spam')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in wrapper
ValueError: Can't use both the old name bar and new name foo. The new name is preferred.
```